# Google Sheets: Activate multiple selection where a range is based on a length of data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code is activating a range in columns G to I from row 4. The ending row is depending on the based on the length of data in column B.

```
function seleziona() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));
  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var Avals = sheetActive.getRange("B4:B").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  sheetActive.getRange(4, 7, Alast, 3).activate();
}
```

I was wandering if there is a way to have a multiple selection (e.g. with getRangeList)that is taking the selection of the above code + the following range: getRange(358, 7, 8, 3)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to activate the range of `sheetActive.getRange(4, 7, Alast, 3)` and `sheetActive.getRange(358, 7, 8, 3)` using the range list.

In this case, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheetActive.getRange(4, 7, Alast, 3).activate();
```

#### To:

```
var rangeList = [
  sheetActive.getRange(4, 7, Alast, 3).getA1Notation(),
  sheetActive.getRange(358, 7, 8, 3).getA1Notation(),
];
sheetActive.getRangeList(rangeList).activate();
```

#### Note:

- If you want to active the range of "Sheet1", you can also use the following modified scriot.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetActive = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var Avals = sheetActive.getRange("B4:B").getValues();
    var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
    var rangeList = [
      sheetActive.getRange(4, 7, Alast, 3).getA1Notation(),
      sheetActive.getRange(358, 7, 8, 3).getA1Notation(),
    ];
    sheetActive.getRangeList(rangeList).activate();
  ```

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#activate())

Comment: perfect! very helpful. Thank you!